# How to get the length of a Riverpod 2 state that is a map?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm having issues accessing my Map state to get the length of the list MartialArtsMove.hand.

Here is my class/provider:

```js
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

enum MartialArtsMove {
  hand,
  kick,
  grab;
}

class OneSteps extends Notifier<Map<MartialArtsMove, List<num>>> {
  @override
  Map<MartialArtsMove, List<num>> build() =>
      {for (final k in MartialArtsMove.values) k: <num>[]};

  void setMove(MartialArtsMove martialArtsMove, List<num> items) {
    state[martialArtsMove] = items;
    ref.notifyListeners();
  }

  void clearAll() {
    for (final martialArtsMove in MartialArtsMove.values) {
      state[martialArtsMove]!.clear();
    }
    ref.notifyListeners();
  }
}

final oneStepsProvider = StateProvider<OneSteps>((_) => OneSteps());
```

and here is how I use it on my page:

```js
var oneStepState = ref.watch(oneStepsProvider);

Text(
                  'Hands ${oneStepState.state[MartialArtsMove.hand]!.length}',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                )
```

I have also tried

```js
Text(
                  'Hands ${oneStepState[MartialArtsMove.hand]!.length}',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a `Notifier` but then exposing it through a `StateProvider`. Those classes are not designed to work together, and in fact the code you shared contains a linter warning that you shouldn't access `Notifier.state` from outside the class. The simplest fix is to change your provider type to `NotifierProvider` and update your ref usage to retrieve the notifier and its state separately:

```dart
typedef OneStepsState = Map<MartialArtsMove, List<num>>;

class OneSteps extends Notifier<OneStepsState> {
    // Unmodified, cut for brevity
}

final oneStepsProvider =
    NotifierProvider<OneSteps, OneStepsState>(() => OneSteps());

// Example of how to access the state and react to changes
class HandsText extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ref) {
    final oneStepState = ref.watch(oneStepsProvider);
    final len = oneStepState[MartialArtsMove.hand]!.length;

    return Text('Hands $len');
  }
}


// Example of how to call the notifier methods
class ClearOneStepsButton extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context, ref) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        ref.read(oneStepsProvider.notifier).clearAll();
      },
      icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
    );
  }
}
```

[Here's a working Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=067fbd870c8416ff5a090cad54c88f17) demonstrating the changes + some other misc refactoring like making the state immutable, which is a bit more idiomatic in Riverpod.

Comment: Thanks for this it looks to mostly be because of the stateprovider vs the notifierprovider for the most part. Thanks for the additional immutable change as well.

Answer (score 0):

StateProvider is the right Provider for cases where you simply want to read and write values.

For cases like the above, you can use a NotifierProvider to have a defined action (method) update the state.

You can read more about this below.

- [NotifierProvider](https://riverpod.dev/ko/docs/providers/notifier_provider)
- [StateProvider](https://riverpod.dev/ko/docs/providers/state_provider)